# context.getSharedPreferences remove or clear not wokring in kotlin

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm using Kotlin. I called the function to delete the saved token, but the token still has a value. What is the problem?

```
    fun setToken(context: ReactContext, token:String) {
     val storage = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
     val editor = storage?.edit()
      editor?.putString(USER_KEY,token);
      editor?.commit()
    }

    fun removeToken(context: ReactContext) {
      val storage = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      val editor = storage?.edit()
      editor?.remove(USER_KEY)
      editor?.commit()
      editor?.clear()
      editor?.commit()
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the token still has value? If the value was stored in a variable then until the variable is reset it will still be avilable. Shared preferences doesnt update variables that took the value from it automatically when changed.

Comment: You can check if it still has a value stored with `storage.contains(USER_KEY)`. Like *cutiko* says, that won't affect your `token` variable, that's a completely separate thing - if you want to clear that, you'll have to make it a `var` and assign a "nothing" value to it (e.g. *null*)

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this, Hopefully It will work.**

```
fun removeToken(context: ReactContext) {
      val storage = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      val editor = storage?.edit()
      editor?.remove(USER_KEY)
      editor?.commit()
      editor?.clear().apply()
    }
```